# Questions on Cakkavala in Buddhist Cosmology

Tags: buddhist-cosmology

I happen to come across the description of Cakkavala as per Buddhist Cosmology from the palikanon website in the link [here](https://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/c/cakkavaala.htm). After going through the information in that link, I have below questions and thought of posting it here to get an answer from the experts here.

1. Where is Mount Sineru located, and can we see it with our eyes?
2. Does a Cakkavala constitute a galaxy or does it imply our observable universe or something else?
3. Are there finite or infinite number of Cakkavala's?
4. This link [here](https://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/b/buddha.htm) mentions that the Buddha is only born in this Cakkavala, my question is why not in other Cakkavala's?
5. Is the physical universe a part of Cakkavala or is it vice versa?

I get that these sort of questions are amongst the imponderables, but curious to know.
Waiting to hear from the experts.

Comment: Related topics (possibly duplicate or at least with potentially-relevant answers): [How can we correlate Buddhist cosmology with astronomical cosmology?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/37481/254) -- and [Can you explain the "Maha Meru"?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/20355/254)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Explanation for Mount Sineru:](http://tibetanbuddhistencyclopedia.com/en/index.php/Sineru) While reading this it is understood the name Sineru Mountain is the same Mahameru Mountain.

It cannot see for laymen human being eyes.  But those who attain "Dhyana" can visit and see these places through there supreme wisdom.

Chakkavala is 31 levels under the One Sun and Moon.  Yes According to Lord Buddha there can be infinite Chakkavala.

Chakkavala is part of universe.

One Chakkavala
[image]

Understand the Universe:  [Explanation for Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe)